# How do I add a custom image to a pageIndicator in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I'm currently developing an app which has a `UIPageViewController`. I want to add a custom icon to one of the pages' indicatorIcon, so it works like the pageIndicator on iOS 9.

For better understanding, here's an image:

[image: Thats how it should look/work like]

It should detect which view is currently displayed and light up the corresponding dot or image. Does someone of you have any idea how we could do that in Swift? Is it possible with the standard pageIndicator in UIKit? If you have any questions please ask them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a GitHub repository that does exactly that. https://github.com/Spaceman-Labs/SMPageControl

Answer (score 0):

As I know it's not possible to implement such customization with native page control.

Take a look at open source libraries FXPageControl & SwipeView. Combine them both to implement paging stuff with customizable page control.